# Upgrading drive D that has program files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I am upgrading my D drive that has a lot of program files (I have an SSD as drive C and install all program files on D). I have installed the new drive (E) and copied everything over from D. Can I decommission D and rename E to D and have it all work?

Comment: Hopefully yes it will work.

Comment: Just leave both drives installed and simply use Disk Manager to change the drive letters.

Comment: If you have copied everything and didn't change any folder names or places, just changing the drive letter from Disk Management should make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After re-boot, the programs worked - except for a strange thing: When I try and run certain Windows executables such as inetsrv, or regedt, I get the message "Specified path does not exist". But it does. I can see the executable in the c:\windows\system32 directory. If I click on the file, I get the same message. I have never seen that before and I am afraid I will have to re-install windows. Any comments?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, that's going to be fine. Enjoy the upgrade.

EDIT (For the pedantic people): Find more on changing drive letters in Windows by following the link below. Simply add your version of windows to the search string if you want to narrow your search results.

https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+change+drive+letter+in+windows

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer.

Comment: "Can I decommission D and rename E to D and have it all work?" The answer is: "Yes". Is there another question here?

Comment: it answers the question it just doesn't tell them how to acomplish it.

Comment: So, the guy upgraded his drive. I expect he can change a drive letter. Either way, the answer to how to change a drive letter is already on a thousand different sites, while the answer to whether or not you can migrate program files to different drives then change drive letters isn't as clear. Don't get hung up on an implied part of the question that isn't even an issue.

Comment: I thought I would provide feedback since I issued a downvote because of quality concerns and the fact I don't find a single statement to be all that helpful to the community as a whole honestly even if it answers the question it doesn't explain how to acomplish it even in the simplest explaination would do.

Comment: That's your prerogative, but an answer can only be as complete as the question. The question here required a yes or no answer. If it was no, I'd have expanded to explain what could be done to accomplish his goal. Understand that not every question requires an essay length answer.

Comment: Without any form of qualifier as to what will be fine (the ability to rename drives, old links to drive content, etc.), this is just a vague statement of opinion.  "the answer to whether or not you can migrate program files to different drives then change drive letters isn't as clear"; even your comment isn't definitive as to what you mean.  With no context to your post, it isn't a reliable answer to the question.

Comment: Perhaps we can arrive at a compromise and you update the answer explaining how to do that? There may be people who are in a similar situation and find this question—it's certainly better to explain a bit more. I know there are yes/no type of questions, but we want to provide more than just that.